# Laptop seems to be stuck in a boot sequence where it wants to boot from hiberfil.sys, which doesnt exist on the harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, boot, laptop, bios, hibernate

So a friend of mine messed up his ASUS K70AB with windows 7 64bit laptop. Probably by closing the lid and removing the power too soon after. He asked if I could take a look at it so I went and tried a couple of things.

The problem is as follows: when the laptop is turned on the harddrive starts spinning and the optical drive makes a sound. After a few sec the fans start spinning too (every now and then). The power button is lit, the led indicator that says the laptop is turned on is lit too, but the harddrive led indicator which should blink at startup and whenever the harddrive is processing doesnt blink even once. The screen is black during this entire process. Basicly: it seems like the laptop wont come out of hibernation, or cant turn on because its bootsequence messes something up, or because it cant read from the harddrive.

At first my thoughts where that the problem was hardware related, maybe the ram data got scrambled, or the sensor that turns on your screen when opening the lid was damaged, or the harddrive could be damaged or in a worse case scenario maybe the motherboard got messed up.

So I switched out the RAM cards with some spare I had laying about, tried the 'remove all power sources and hold the power button 30sec' trick and I tried to reset bios/cmos settings by removing/inserting the small 3v battery.
During all these attempts the laptop booted a few times, but completely at random. Meaning that it wouldnt turn on right after I hit the power button, but sometimes like an hour later. And if it did, it gave me an error message saying there was something wrong with hiberfil.sys. Every time it booted, it would boot perfectly fine (and instantly) the second time I would turn it on, but then the third or fourth time it would 'boot' as stated in the problem again.

Then when the laptop wouldnt boot anymore (not even after leaving it 'on' for 24h), I tested the harddrive by putting it in a similar laptop. It booted fine but gave me the error message about hiberfil.sys again. I read about the 'powercfg -h off' to disable the hibernation, so I tried doing that (not sure if that setting would be saved on the harddrive or on the bios settings of the laptop) but it didnt help when I put the harddrive back in the faulty laptop.

So because of the error message the problem could lie with hiberfil.sys, but since the 'power on' led indicator isnt blinking but is constantly on it doesnt seem like its stuck in hibernation mode, but more like it cant boot for some reason.

Since the screen doesnt even go on (ie. It doesnt light up as if it wants to go on, it just remains black as if its off) I'm thinkin the problem lies either with the boot sequence in the bios that wants to boot from hiberfil.sys (which doesnt exist), or that the motherboard is just faulty.

Can anyone help me with suggestions on what to try next or just your opinion on the matter?
I dont like to tell my friend 'dude your motherboard is done, I cant help you' without knowing a 100% sure.

Comment: just looking at the title, this is a long shot..and perhaps not a first or second resort..  edit the registry from Win PE and set the registry value so as to disable hibernation. but where that key and value is and how is not anywhere near the top of my head!

Comment: I cant get into the register on the faulty laptop, would it work if i put the harddrive in another similar laptop?

Comment: reading the body of what you wrote, you managed to boot putting the hard drive in another laptop.. and disabled hibernation from there no need for the registry, but it still didn't help. Have you done F8(possibly need to hit f8 twice) and Repair and 'Startup Repair' http://res1.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows%207/main/65a1558c-4130-45c3-93b4-e1de3c40739d_0.jpg

Comment: Yeah, thing is it doesnt even reach the point where you can press any button, basicly the power on indicator is on, but the laptop is 'off'

Comment: any luck putting a blank hard drive in and trying to install windows on that?  if not, then that would rule out anything to do with hiberfil.sys  And how about any luck booting an OS from USB(just as a test)? e.g. something from pendrivelinux.com

Comment: Good call! I Will try that :) ill post the result

Comment: You should start by using Startup Repair...